# Ubuntu 12.04 does a restart instead of a shutdown

Tags: shutdown, restart

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 on my Dell Latitude D630C.

Now, when I want to shut down the system does shut down but then starts up again immediately. It's like it does a reboot instead of a shut down.

Comment: This also happens with the Toshiba Satellite C670D-108 but only when the mains power is active. To shutdown without restart I have to pull the power connector.

Comment: @paulb1257 interesting! mine was the exact opposite. I have to plug in my power connector so my system would shutdown properly. If I shut it down while it's on battery, it just would do a restart. 

maybe the laptop_mode setting is somehow related to this issue. mine is ON(1) when on battery mode, while OFF(0) when on AC mode.

Comment: no, i guess i'm wrong. i tried disabling laptop_mode on battery, but it still reboot when i shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

I have had exactly the same problem on my Acer V5-571G: the laptop shuts down, turns off its power LED, and then starts again after a few seconds.

The problem seems to arise from incorrect work of pm-utils (which are replacement for laptop-mode-tools). But if you write `on` into `/sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/control`, the kernel takes control over power management at the specified devices - and somehow this makes the hardware to shut down correctly.

So I have written a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  stop) for i in /sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/control ; do echo on > $i ; done 
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

and to make it being executed every time before shutdown I've placed it under name K32power-control-on into /etc/rc0.d directory (don't forget to make the script executable, sudo chmod +x K32power-control-on). After that the laptop shuts down ok.

I think that there are only a few buses/devices which need to have 'on' value written to their power/control, so the list of devices in the script can be restricted, but I just didn't investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in with my PC, but the first time it can be normally shutdown. Then, after a few days it can't be shutdown and always restart. After I had reinstalled the grub using boot-repair, because I formatted my windows, my PC could be shutdown normally as the first time.

You can obtain boot-repair here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Hope this answer help you.

NB: I used boot-repair with live-usb and sorry if my english doesn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my new Acer Aspire v5 notebook. It has been solved by enabling laptop-mode by running

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

Hope it will help you.